# How to ignore PressAndHold event in Qt?

Tags: qt, qml

I have MouseArea with onPressAndHold event and set pressAndHoldInterval for 5 seconds. Sometimes when I am holding mouse button to execute this PressAndHold event Popup window appears. If I release mouse button after 5 seconds, PressAndHold event is called for this MouseArea under the Popup window. Is there some way for ignoring this PressAndHold event when that MouseArea is overlapped by Popup window?

In other words, PressAndHold event begins when I press and hold mouse button on MouseArea. Popup window appears and I would like to reject/ignore this PressAndHold event. Now when I release the mouse button the PressAndHold event is called.

I tried adding MouseArea to Popup and setting propagateComposedEvents but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Can't you simply put an if statement in the event handler? Like `onPressAndHold: if(!popup.isOpen()) { // do something}` to execute the code only if the popup is not open

Comment: @daljit97 Yes, I can do it in that way, but I am wondering if there is some smarter solution.

Comment: @qbranchmaster I think there is no need to overengineer something when you have a simple solution.